# Cannot save Shared preferences, it crashes because the context is null, fragment already replaced

Tags: android, android-activity, null, fragment, android-context

The app was first made with activities, but because of an issue, I have to use 2 fragments with an `FragmentManager` instead. Now, because of this I had to refactor a lot of code.
So my 2 fragments are an `videoplayerfragment` and `videoRecorderFragment`.
Sometimes I send an request to get via a JSON, the list of videos in the videoPlayer, and if I want to make a video, I change the fragment. Now if the response is late, I will get the OnSuccess of the request, trying to save the credentials, but the context of the videoplayer is null, because I have replaced the fragment.

This is part of the `UserCredentialsPersistence` class:

```
 private static SharedPreferences obtainSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(USER_CREDENTIALS_KEY,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

 public static boolean saveToDownloadCount(Context context,
        int download_count) {

    Editor e = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_CREDENTIALS_KEY,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    e.putInt(USER_TO_DL_COUNT_KEY, download_count);
    return e.commit();
}
```

This is the important part of the `VideoPlayerFragment`:

```
    videoRequest.requestNotification = new RequestNotification() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object sender) {
            Log.d("@VideoPlayerActivity", "success");
            playHideUpAnimation();
            new_videos = new ArrayList<VideoData>(VideoDataManager.getInstance().getNewVideos());           
UserCredentialsPersistence.saveToDownloadCount(getActivity(), UserCredentialsPersistence.restoreToDownloadCount(getActivity()) + new_videos.size());
            all_videos = videodb.getTotalVideoListFromDB();
```

Here it crashes because the `getActivity` is null when calling any method from `UserCredentialsPersistence`.

I have also tried to call it from the `FragmentManager:
OnSuccess` at the `requestNotification` calling:

```
((VideoHolderActivity) getActivity()).saveToDLCount(new_videos.size());
```

And this being:

```
 public void saveToDLCount(Integer size){
    UserCredentialsPersistence.saveToDownloadCount(VideoHolderActivity.this, UserCredentialsPersistence.restoreToDownloadCount(VideoHolderActivity.this) + size);
}
```

But still, the context is null. Any idea how I can get past this?

Comment: replace it with getApplicationContext(). It will work fine.

Comment: I tried this, but i cannot put only getApplicationContext, because it does not recognise it, so i have tried `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` , it works better, but still it crashes some times, any ideeas what could be done?

Comment: context.getApplicationContext(). This is what you should try. There is no activity at that time so you should use Applications context. You can even keep a static context reference at the start of the app.

Comment: but is it safe to keep a static context refference? won't that produce memory leaks? I've created a listener to the activity, and call the parts of my code into the activity, that needed the context. I am still experimenting with this, but i think this would be good

Comment: nope. In this case its all OK. Memory leaks are related to Activity in this case. You are trying to use a reference of an activity which is not there any more = memory leak. Its better to use shared prefs with app context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a BaseFragment class. All my Fragments extend this class. And in this class I have a 
interface, which is implemented by my FragmentNavigator.

Then i simply call from the fragments the functions that i need from the FragmentManager. Here i have put all the functions that need context. And after getting the response from them, i send it back into the fragments, by doing a cast to the current fragment i use.